# Use of @Scope annotation with Spring Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I am working on a project which is based on Struts 1.x, converting it to Spring 4. I have visited many tutorial sites and read Spring 4 tutorials but no one used `@Scope` annotation with `@Controller` in tutorial application. My Question is :

1) Is it compulsory to use `@Scope` attribute?

2) What if we do not use?

3) Is it good practice to use `@Scope` with `@Controller`?

We have also reading a property file at server start up and storing it into Property class. I am reading some property in DAOImpl class(Annotated as `@Repository`). If I use `@Scope` attribute with both Controller and Repository then it return value otherwise it return `NullPointerException`. Why is this behavior?

Comment: What do you think `@Scope` does?

Comment: OrangDog As per my knowledge @Scope allow us to initialize object in different scope. Like singleton, prototype, request and session

Comment: Can you post that DaoImplCode?

Comment: Why would you need to have more than one instance of a controller class?

Comment: We are using @Autowired for instantiating DAOImpl objectin controlle. So just want to be sure that it does not cause ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is it compulsory to use `@Scope` attribute?

No. If you want the default (["singleton"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#SCOPE_SINGLETON)) then you don't need to specify.

> 2) What if we do not use?

Then your application will only create one instance of the bean.

> 3) Is it good practice to use `@Scope` with `@Controller`?

No. It does not make sense for an application to have more than one instance of a controller class (or a repository). If you have a need to use both annotations together, then you are not modelling your classes very well.

> Why is this behavior?

Because the context cannot create a scoped bean to inject if the target bean is not being constructed in that scope (e.g. trying to inject a request-scoped bean into a bean that's being created outside the context of a request).

To solve this you need to use scoped-proxies, by setting [`proxyMode`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html#proxyMode--).

In your specific case, however, the solution is that you don't actually need non-default scope.

Answer (score 0):

@Scope- Isn't Compulsory to use with @Controller, unless and until u need one based on your requirements. @Scope defines the scope of the bean, by default its singleton. 
And also, Property Class should be managed by Spring, otherwise it will give you an exception.